# Prevent default for controller and directive on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the table with two click actions – first one is click on a whole row responsible for opening feedback, second one is click on name which add the item to the team.

```
<div id="content_people" ng-show="active=='people'" ng-controller="DevsListCtrl">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tbody ng-repeat="d in $data" ng-controller="feedbackCtrl">
            <tr ng-click="onItemClick(d.name,$event)">
                <td add-new-team-member data-title='name' data-value="{{d}}">{{d.name}}</td>
                <td data-title='age'>{{d.age}}</td>
                <td data-title='grade'>{{d.grade}}</td>
                <td data-title='job'>{{d.job}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="isOpen(d.name)" ng-repeat = "f in getFeedback(d.name)" >
                <td colspan="4" width="100%">
                    {{f}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="isOpen(d.name)">
                <td colspan="4" width="100%" ng-form="feedbackForm">
                    <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="comment" ng-minlength="10" required>
                    <input ng-click="submitNewFeedback(d.name, comment)" type="submit" value="Add new feedback" ng-disabled="feedbackForm.$invalid" >
                <td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Currently click on a whole row open feedback section as well. I would like to prevent this and looking for solution as we have similar in directive case:

```
mainApp.directive("addNewTeamMember", ['teamSharedObj', function (teamSharedObj) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(scope.teamMemberName)
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    if (typeof teamSharedObj.selected == 'undefined') {
                        alert("No team. Please select team.");
                        return;
                    }

                    var result = [];
                    var asObject = JSON.parse(attrs.value);
                    result.push(asObject);
                    teamSharedObj.addTeamMembers(teamSharedObj.selected, result);
                });
            });
//            element.on('click', function(e){
//                e.preventDefault();
//            });
        }
    }
}])
```

I try different cases but nothing works. The most popular advice is to use an event to prevent others action hits:

```
$scope.clicked = function(what, event) {
    alert(what + ' clicked');
    if(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

My controller is:

```
mainApp.controller("feedbackCtrl", [ '$scope', 'teamSharedObj', function($scope, teamSharedObj) {
    // control visibility state
    $scope.state = 'off';
    $scope.selected = "undefined";
    $scope.isOpen = function(employee) {
        return $scope.state === "on" && $scope.selected === employee;
    }
    // handle click on item
    $scope.onItemClick = function(employee, event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.state = ($scope.state === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on');
        $scope.selected = employee;
    }
    // open appropriate feedback container
    $scope.getFeedback = function(employee) {
        var result = teamSharedObj.feedback[employee] ? teamSharedObj.feedback[employee] : "<div> No values </div>";
        return result ;
    }
    $scope.submitNewFeedback = function(employee, feedback) {
        teamSharedObj.addFeedback(employee, feedback);
    }
}]);
```

I found that directive click which is inside row invokes first and only then controller click is hit. I put preventDefault on both but issue still the same. Do you have any thoughts that can be helpfull in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the following:

A click on a `td` with the `add-new-team-member` attribute should only fire the click event handler in the directive.

A click anywhere else on the row should fire the `onItemClick` function in the controller.

`preventDefault` will not help you with this since it only prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

What you need for this is `stopPropagation`, which stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

Simplified version of what you have:

```
<tr controller-event-listener>
  <td directive-event-listener>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you click on the `td` and don't want the event to bubble up to the `tr`, you need to call `stopPropagation`.

Putting this in your directive should be enough:

```
element.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Actually I don't follow the best practice in this case. I had received a feedback and rewrite this code putting all this operations in one controller and extract some functionality in services. After that stopPropagation works fine. Thank you for your help, upvote your post